# WhatDoIHave and AssertConfigurationIsValid missing in StructureMap v3

Tags: structuremap, structuremap3

I'm getting the dreaded "No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type" even though I have set a registry for the default conventions.

To debug I am trying the WhatDoIHave and Asset... methods but these no longer exist on ObjectFactory. Am I missing something or have these been removed in the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeremy Miller explains new improved error reporting in SM3 3.0 [here](http://jeremydmiller.com/2014/02/18/structuremap-3-is-gonna-tell-you-whats-wrong-and-where-it-hurts/).

"WhatDoIHave" remains in SM 3:
(taken from the above blog entry)

```
   [Test]
    public void what_do_I_have()
    {
        var container = new Container(x => {
            x.For<IDevice>().AddInstances(o => {
                o.Type<ADevice>().Named("A");
                o.Type<BDevice>().Named("B").LifecycleIs<ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle>();
                o.Type<CDevice>().Named("C").Singleton();
            });

            x.For<IDevice>().UseIfNone<DefaultDevice>();
        });

        Debug.WriteLine(container.WhatDoIHave());

        Debug.WriteLine(container.WhatDoIHave(pluginType:typeof(IDevice)));
    }
```

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to just to break on Exception when StructureMap fails and then add a watch for "Container.AssertConfigurationIsValid()". This spelled out my exact issue when I had the same problem.